# Fedora 29, Intel HD audio, no sound from speakers or headphone jack

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio

I am using Fedora 29 and am not able to get any sound out of my machine. As far as the operating system is concerned (when using alsamixer, pavucontrol, etc.) sound should be working, nothing is muted or anything like that, but no sound is coming from speakers or from the headphone jack. I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling pulseaudio, tried some things like creating /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf (have also tried calling it /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf) with various model options e.g:

```
# cat /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf
options snd_hda_intel model=imac27
```

This is a 27" iMac (iMac18,3)

I have posted some relevant info about the system below, let me know if any further info is required. If someone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Perhaps this might clue someone in for a start?

```
# aplay /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/bark.ogg
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

aplay: main:828: audio open error: Connection refused
```

(yes I have googled this error quite extensively)

General info:

```
# uname -r
4.20.4-200.fc29.x86_64

# lspci | grep Audio

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 570/580]
```

I just want the normal built in speakers and headphone jack, as these machines are to be deployed in educational labs, I'm not interested in getting the HDMI audio going (Radeon device).

```
# lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_generic    90112  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_intel          49152  7
snd_hda_codec         155648  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           98304  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq                86016  0
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_pcm               118784  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    94208  22 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd

# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output from

```
# alsa-info.sh --upload
```

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d4a05b5de509214a20cb2191dc3d9fbbbe377814