# No sound from speakers/headphones and no Mic on iMac 2019 (18,3) running Linux

Tags: audio, macintosh, intel

My 2019 iMac (18,3) has no sound through the speakers/headphones and no Mic when running Linux: **it works as expected on OSX**.

I am posting here because this appears to be a Linux issue, as I have three different distros installed -- **Manjaro** (kernel *5.6-x86_64* (though I have tried 6.0 too)); **Fedora 31** (kernel *5.1.20-300*); and **Ubuntu 19.10** (kernel *5.3.0-45-generic*) -- and none of them produce sound or record it from the mic.

The `Audio Device` from `lspci` is `Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)`.  It also appears to control the PCI Bridge and the USB controller.  I have posted more information [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-sound-from-speakers-or-headphones-2019-imac18-3/96480).

I have looked at both `pavucontrol` and `alsamixer`, but have found nothing to suggest that the operating systems don't think the Audio Device is working.  It's just that no sound comes out.  In `pavucontrol`, the `Configuration` is set to HDMI off, and `Built-in Audio` as `Analog Stereo Duplex` -- though none of them change the outcome.  In `alsamixer`, the Chip is identified as `Cirrus Logic Generic`, which is incorrect, and there are no speaker/headphone/anything columns other than PCH.

As suggested in [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/alsa/mailman/message/36452074/), I tried to fiddle with `/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf` by adding `options snd_hda_intel model=intel-mac-auto` and various other iterations (e.g., `options snd_hda_intel model=imac27` see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002258/no-sound-on-imac27-latest) for why).  Installing XFCE and modifying the settings there did not work for me.

There are similar posts about not getting sound of of the newer (post-2017) iMacs, which can best be found by just searching Google with `snd-hda-intel imac 18,3`.  That the problem spans all distros ([Fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500724/fedora-29-intel-hd-audio-no-sound-from-speakers-or-headphone-jack/509618); [LinuxMint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=312668&sid=038d00dd76f25cf0c2ce0eeb49a9b168&start=20); [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002258/no-sound-on-imac27-latest); [Manjaro](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sound-not-working-on-a-2017-imac-27-5k-retina/43638)) suggests a kernel or driver issue.

**Any idea either (A) how to fix or (B) where I can post this get someone to build this audio device into the kernel??**

Adding `dmesg`.  There are no recent `journalctl` entries related to sound.  This is for Manjaro 20.0 running 5.6.5-1-MANJARO.

```
   [    0.315571] Modules linked in:
    [    0.315572] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G        W         5.6.5-1-MANJARO #1
    [    0.315573] Hardware name: Apple Inc. iMac18,3/Mac-BE088AF8C5EB4FA2, BIOS 181.0.0.0.0 01/31/2020
    [    0.315574] RIP: 0010:acpi_ec_add.cold+0xe3/0x105
    [    0.315580] Call Trace:
    [    0.315582]  acpi_device_probe+0x47/0x1d0
    [    0.315583]  really_probe+0x147/0x3c0
    [    0.315584]  driver_probe_device+0xb6/0x100
    [    0.315585]  ? driver_allows_async_probing+0x50/0x50
    [    0.315586]  bus_for_each_drv+0x8f/0xd0
    [    0.315587]  __device_attach+0xf0/0x170
    [    0.315588]  ? acpi_sleep_proc_init+0x24/0x24
    [    0.315589]  acpi_bus_register_early_device+0x4a/0x70
    [    0.315591]  acpi_ec_init+0x17c/0x1a8
    [    0.315592]  acpi_init+0x2d4/0x33a
    [    0.315594]  do_one_initcall+0x59/0x240
    [    0.315596]  kernel_init_freeable+0x1b2/0x214
    [    0.315597]  ? rest_init+0xbf/0xbf
    [    0.315598]  kernel_init+0xa/0x101
    [    0.315599]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
    [    0.315600] ---[ end trace 73e60983eec368c9 ]---
    [    0.315625] iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
    [    0.315633] pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=none,locks=none
    [    0.315633] pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
    [    0.315633] pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: setting as boot device
    [    0.315633] vgaarb: loaded
    [    0.315769] SCSI subsystem initialized
    [    0.315778] libata version 3.00 loaded.
    [    0.315778] ACPI: bus type USB registered
    [    0.315778] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    [    0.315778] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
    [    0.315778] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    [    0.315778] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
    [    0.315778] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
    [    0.315778] PTP clock support registered
    [    0.315778] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
    [    0.315937] Registered efivars operations
    [    0.315937] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
    [    0.334438] PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
    [    0.334886] NetLabel: Initializing
    [    0.334887] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
    [    0.334887] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
    [    0.334895] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
    [    0.334898] hpet0: at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    [    0.334898] hpet0: 8 comparators, 64-bit 24.000000 MHz counter
    [    0.336696] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc-early
    [    0.343575] *** VALIDATE bpf ***
    [    0.343634] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
    [    0.343643] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
    [    0.343663] *** VALIDATE ramfs ***
    [    0.343665] *** VALIDATE hugetlbfs ***
    [    0.343692] pnp: PnP ACPI init
    [    0.344068] system 00:00: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed03fff] has been reserved
    [    0.344072] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0103 PNP0c01 (active)
    [    0.344102] system 00:01: [io  0xffff] has been reserved
    [    0.344103] system 00:01: [io  0x1800-0x18fe] has been reserved
    [    0.344104] system 00:01: [io  0x0800-0x087f] has been reserved
    [    0.344106] system 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
    [    0.344119] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
    [    0.344282] system 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
    [    0.344385] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 4 devices
    [    0.345184] pci 0000:01:00.0: assigning 79 device properties
    [    0.345212] pci 0000:07:00.0: assigning 8 device properties
    [    0.345217] pci 0000:00:1f.3: assigning 4 device properties
    [    0.345221] apple-properties: device path parse error -19 at 0x14:
    [    0.345222] apple-properties: 00000000: 52 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 01 0c 00 d0 41 03 0a  R............A..
    [    0.345223] apple-properties: 00000010: 00 00 00 00 01 01 06 00 00 02 7f ff 04 00 2c 00  ..............,.
    [    0.345224] apple-properties: 00000020: 00 00 41 00 41 00 50 00 4c 00 2c 00 69 00 67 00  ..A.A.P.L.,.i.g.
    [    0.345224] apple-properties: 00000030: 2d 00 70 00 6c 00 61 00 74 00 66 00 6f 00 72 00  -.p.l.a.t.f.o.r.
    [    0.345225] apple-properties: 00000040: 6d 00 2d 00 69 00 64 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 03 00  m.-.i.d.........
    [    0.345225] apple-properties: 00000050: 12 59                                            .Y
    [    0.349746] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
    [    0.349769] pci 0000:06:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 09-41] add_size 1000
    [    0.349770] pci 0000:06:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 08] add_size 1000
    [    0.349772] pci 0000:06:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 08] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
    [    0.349773] pci 0000:06:04.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 42-7a] add_size 1000
    [    0.349774] pci 0000:05:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 06-7a] add_size 3000
    [    0.349784] pci 0000:00:1f.3: BAR 4: assigned [mem 0x90000000-0x9000ffff 64bit]
    [    0.349793] pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
    [    0.349795] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
    [    0.349796] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0x92600000-0x926fffff]
    [    0.349798] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xc0000000-0xd01fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349800] pci 0000:00:1b.0: PCI bridge to [bus 02]
    [    0.349805] pci 0000:00:1b.0:   bridge window [mem 0x92500000-0x925fffff]
    [    0.349810] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
    [    0.349814] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0x92000000-0x924fffff]
    [    0.349819] pci 0000:00:1c.1: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
    [    0.349823] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [mem 0xd0200000-0xd02fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349827] pci 0000:05:00.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x5000-0x7fff]
    [    0.349830] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
    [    0.349831] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
    [    0.349832] pci 0000:06:01.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
    [    0.349833] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x6000-0x6fff]
    [    0.349833] pci 0000:06:04.0: BAR 13: assigned [io  0x7000-0x7fff]
    [    0.349835] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
    [    0.349836] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
    [    0.349837] pci 0000:06:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 07]
    [    0.349841] pci 0000:06:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x92900000-0x929fffff]
    [    0.349847] pci 0000:06:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 09-41]
    [    0.349849] pci 0000:06:01.0:   bridge window [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
    [    0.349853] pci 0000:06:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0x92a00000-0x999fffff]
    [    0.349856] pci 0000:06:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0300000-0xd72fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349861] pci 0000:08:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x92800000-0x9280ffff]
    [    0.349865] pci 0000:06:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 08]
    [    0.349866] pci 0000:06:02.0:   bridge window [io  0x6000-0x6fff]
    [    0.349870] pci 0000:06:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0x92800000-0x928fffff]
    [    0.349877] pci 0000:06:04.0: PCI bridge to [bus 42-7a]
    [    0.349878] pci 0000:06:04.0:   bridge window [io  0x7000-0x7fff]
    [    0.349882] pci 0000:06:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0x99a00000-0xa09fffff]
    [    0.349885] pci 0000:06:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd7300000-0xde2fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349889] pci 0000:05:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 06-7a]
    [    0.349891] pci 0000:05:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x5000-0x7fff]
    [    0.349895] pci 0000:05:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x92800000-0xa09fffff]
    [    0.349897] pci 0000:05:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd0300000-0xde2fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349902] pci 0000:00:1c.4: PCI bridge to [bus 05-7a]
    [    0.349903] pci 0000:00:1c.4:   bridge window [io  0x5000-0x8fff]
    [    0.349906] pci 0000:00:1c.4:   bridge window [mem 0x92800000-0xa09fffff]
    [    0.349907] pci 0000:00:1c.4:   bridge window [mem 0xd0300000-0xde2fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349911] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
    [    0.349912] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
    [    0.349913] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
    [    0.349913] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000c3fff window]
    [    0.349914] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0x000c4000-0x000c7fff window]
    [    0.349915] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 9 [mem 0x000c8000-0x000cbfff window]
    [    0.349916] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 10 [mem 0x000cc000-0x000cffff window]
    [    0.349916] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 11 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff window]
    [    0.349917] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 12 [mem 0x000d4000-0x000d7fff window]
    [    0.349918] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 13 [mem 0x000d8000-0x000dbfff window]
    [    0.349919] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 14 [mem 0x000dc000-0x000dffff window]
    [    0.349919] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 15 [mem 0x000e0000-0x000e3fff window]
    [    0.349920] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 16 [mem 0x000e4000-0x000e7fff window]
    [    0.349921] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 17 [mem 0x000e8000-0x000ebfff window]
    [    0.349921] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 18 [mem 0x000ec000-0x000effff window]
    [    0.349922] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 19 [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff window]
    [    0.349923] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 20 [mem 0x90000000-0xfeafffff window]
    [    0.349924] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 0 [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
    [    0.349924] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 1 [mem 0x92600000-0x926fffff]
    [    0.349925] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 2 [mem 0xc0000000-0xd01fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349926] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0x92500000-0x925fffff]
    [    0.349927] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 1 [mem 0x92000000-0x924fffff]
    [    0.349928] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 2 [mem 0xd0200000-0xd02fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349928] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 0 [io  0x5000-0x8fff]
    [    0.349929] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 1 [mem 0x92800000-0xa09fffff]
    [    0.349930] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 2 [mem 0xd0300000-0xde2fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349931] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 0 [io  0x5000-0x7fff]
    [    0.349931] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 1 [mem 0x92800000-0xa09fffff]
    [    0.349932] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 2 [mem 0xd0300000-0xde2fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349933] pci_bus 0000:07: resource 1 [mem 0x92900000-0x929fffff]
    [    0.349934] pci_bus 0000:09: resource 0 [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
    [    0.349934] pci_bus 0000:09: resource 1 [mem 0x92a00000-0x999fffff]
    [    0.349935] pci_bus 0000:09: resource 2 [mem 0xd0300000-0xd72fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.349936] pci_bus 0000:08: resource 0 [io  0x6000-0x6fff]
    [    0.349936] pci_bus 0000:08: resource 1 [mem 0x92800000-0x928fffff]
    [    0.349937] pci_bus 0000:42: resource 0 [io  0x7000-0x7fff]
    [    0.349938] pci_bus 0000:42: resource 1 [mem 0x99a00000-0xa09fffff]
    [    0.349938] pci_bus 0000:42: resource 2 [mem 0xd7300000-0xde2fffff 64bit pref]
    [    0.350028] NET: Registered protocol family 2
    [    0.350113] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
    [    0.350142] TCP established hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
    [    0.350244] TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
    [    0.350293] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 65536 bind 65536)
    [    0.350321] UDP hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
    [    0.350337] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 4096 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
    [    0.350384] NET: Registered protocol family 1
    [    0.350387] NET: Registered protocol family 44
    [    0.350591] pci 0000:01:00.1: D0 power state depends on 0000:01:00.0
    [    0.350911] pci 0000:08:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [    0.350982] PCI: CLS 256 bytes, default 64
    [    0.351009] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
    [    0.505437] Freeing initrd memory: 14080K
    [    0.529021] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
    [    0.529025] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x70f70000-0x74f70000] (64MB)
    [    0.529159] check: Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
    [    0.529386] Initialise system trusted keyrings
    [    0.529393] Key type blacklist registered
    [    0.529427] workingset: timestamp_bits=41 max_order=21 bucket_order=0
    [    0.530267] zbud: loaded
    [    0.533625] Key type asymmetric registered
    [    0.533625] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
    [    0.533631] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 245)
    [    0.533658] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
    [    0.533658] io scheduler kyber registered
    [    0.533676] io scheduler bfq registered
    [    0.534693] pcieport 0000:06:01.0: pciehp: Slot #1 AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug+ Surprise+ Interlock- NoCompl+ LLActRep+
    [    0.534856] pcieport 0000:06:02.0: pciehp: Slot #0 AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug+ Surprise+ Interlock- NoCompl+ LLActRep+
    [    0.535037] pcieport 0000:06:04.0: pciehp: Slot #4 AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug+ Surprise+ Interlock- NoCompl+ LLActRep+
    [    0.535159] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
    [    0.535205] efifb: probing for efifb
    [    0.535244] efifb: No BGRT, not showing boot graphics
    [    0.535245] efifb: framebuffer at 0xc0300000, using 32400k, total 32400k
    [    0.535245] efifb: mode is 3840x2160x32, linelength=15360, pages=1
    [    0.535246] efifb: scrolling: redraw
    [    0.535247] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
    [    0.535273] fbcon: Deferring console take-over
    [    0.535274] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
    [    0.535278] intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x142120
    [    0.535279] intel_idle: v0.4.1 model 0x9E
    [    0.535462] intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
    [    0.535523] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
    [    0.535539] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
    [    0.535562] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
    [    0.535574] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
    [    0.535591] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
    [    0.539080] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
    [    0.539118] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(GFX0) defines _DOD but not _DOS
    [    0.539140] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
    [    0.541040] acpi device:02: registered as cooling_device0
    [    0.541060] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input3
    [    0.545901] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
    [    0.546305] AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <jroedel@suse.de>
    [    0.546306] AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
    [    0.546874] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:02:00.0
    [    0.546892] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
    [    0.547089] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
    [    0.547091] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm led clo only pio slum part ems deso sadm sds apst 
    [    0.547310] scsi host0: ahci
    [    0.547357] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0x9272b800 port 0x9272b900 irq 36
    [    0.547389] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
    [    0.547392] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
    [    0.547406] rtc_cmos 00:02: RTC can wake from S4
    [    0.547874] rtc_cmos 00:02: registered as rtc0
    [    0.547883] rtc_cmos 00:02: alarms up to one month, y3k, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
    [    0.547915] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
    [    0.547926] intel_pstate: Disabling energy efficiency optimization
    [    0.548439] intel_pstate: HWP enabled
    [    0.548525] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
    [    0.548740] intel_pmc_core intel_pmc_core.0:  initialized
    [    0.548801] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
    [    0.549267] NET: Registered protocol family 10
    [    0.570938] Segment Routing with IPv6
    [    0.570993] NET: Registered protocol family 17
    [    0.572066] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
    [    0.572162] microcode: sig=0x906e9, pf=0x2, revision=0xca
    [    0.572447] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
    [    0.572456] IPI shorthand broadcast: enabled
    [    0.572476] sched_clock: Marking stable (575440031, -3012466)->(575623611, -3196046)
    [    0.572833] registered taskstats version 1
    [    0.572854] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
    [    0.585212] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: 97bd00d60515dad50e349ce022fedf2318a47e1b'
    [    0.585284] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
    [    0.585672] Key type ._fscrypt registered
    [    0.585675] Key type .fscrypt registered
    [    0.585677] Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
    [    0.606425] Key type big_key registered
    [    0.608117] PM:   Magic number: 0:338:456
    [    0.608159] mem urandom: hash matches
    [    0.608388] rtc_cmos 00:02: setting system clock to 2020-04-19T00:28:17 UTC (1587256097)
    [    0.862587] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
    [    0.863553] ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
    [    0.863844] ata1.00: ATA-9: APPLE HDD ST1000DM003, AQ04, max UDMA/133
    [    0.863850] ata1.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
    [    0.865125] ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
    [    0.865313] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
    [    1.518624] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
    [    1.518628] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
    [    1.519685] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000001109810
    [    1.519693] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 256 is not supported
    [   14.349204] audit: type=1130 audit(1587256111.237:5): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-sysctl comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
    [   14.950800] audit: type=1130 audit(1587256111.837:6): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-sysusers comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
    [   15.791502] audit: type=1130 audit(1587256112.677:7): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
    [   15.791878] audit: type=1334 audit(1587256112.677:8): prog-id=5 op=LOAD
    [   15.791936] audit: type=1334 audit(1587256112.677:9): prog-id=6 op=LOAD
    [   17.215118] audit: type=1130 audit(1587256114.100:10): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-journal-flush comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
    [   17.505882] audit: type=1130 audit(1587256114.394:11): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-udevd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
    [   17.681509] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input22
    [   17.707721] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SPD Write Disable is set
    [   17.707752] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus using PCI interrupt
    [   18.164980] tg3.c:v3.137 (May 11, 2014)
    [   18.179669] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
    [   18.188593] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 4 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
    [   18.188594] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
    [   18.188594] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
    [   18.188595] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-14 Joules
    [   18.188595] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
    [   18.202083] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
    [   18.211346] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [   18.211445] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Force to non-snoop mode
    [   18.272107] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input23
    [   18.272137] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input24
    [   18.272166] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input25
    [   18.272260] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input26
    [   18.272285] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input27
    [   18.272310] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input28
    [   18.272415] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input29
    [   18.281692] tg3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: Tigon3 [partno(BCM957766a) rev 57766001] (PCI Express) MAC address 68:sd:f7:0a:sd:43
    [   18.281694] tg3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: attached PHY is 57765 (10/100/1000Base-T Ethernet) (WireSpeed[1], EEE[1])
    [   18.281695] tg3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RXcsums[1] LinkChgREG[0] MIirq[0] ASF[0] TSOcap[1]
    [   18.281696] tg3 0000:04:00.0 eth0: dma_rwctrl[00000001] dma_mask[64-bit]
    [   18.288242] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for Generic: line_outs=2 (0x24/0x25/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
    [   18.288244] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
    [   18.288245] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x2c/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
    [   18.288245] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
    [   18.288246] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
    [   18.288247] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x45
    [   18.288247] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x3c
    [   18.318923] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
    [   18.466211] applesmc: key=769 fan=1 temp=97 index=93 acc=0 lux=2 kbd=0
    [   18.466312] applesmc applesmc.768: hwmon_device_register() is deprecated. Please convert the driver to use hwmon_device_register_with_info().
    [   18.469846] iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
    [   18.470145] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
    [   18.471326] iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
    [   18.471423] iTCO_wdt: unable to reset NO_REBOOT flag, device disabled by hardware/BIOS
    [   18.576035] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/1
    [   18.660255] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Apple Inc.-iMac18,3.txt failed with error -2
    [   18.660295] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
    [   18.844334] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
    [   18.844339] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
    [   18.844342] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
    [   18.844345] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
    [   18.895707] tg3 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0f0: renamed from eth0
    [   19.152077] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/1
    [   19.152112] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
    [   19.152867] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43602/1 wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
```

Adding kernel parameters:  `rw quiet acpi=off acpi_osi=!Darwin acpi_backlight=video mds=full,nosmt`.  Note that I tried with `acpi=off` added to these and also with `acpi=off` being the sole `acpi` parameter (i.e., not `acpi_osi` and not `acpi_backlight`, which fix the iMac not being able to sleep and no brightness controls, respectively).  Still no sound.

Comment: Let's start by sharing logs (dmesg, journalctl) from one distro our your installed

Comment: Added `dmesg` in the original post.  Not much `journalctl` relevant to sound in the recent period.

Comment: I remember I looked deeply into this and went through lots of forums. I was not able to solve it and just gave up. Potentially, the Linux kernel doesn't support the later macs (I have a Macbook and iMAC for work). Speakers do not play on linux.

Comment: I dove deeply into this with my 2017 imac18,2 running at that time I believe (late 2018) F29, posting alsa logs, looking everywhere. Now I'm on F33 and while the dimming doesn't work now for some reason. Still no love from the speakers. They definitely work under osx however.
I think the problem with typical tests is that the kernel thinks that the speakers are fine. It is a frustrating and mysterious problem and all I can think to do is flip Apple the bird.

Comment: Did you actually fix this problem ? This is interesting for me...

Comment: Nope.  Nothing worked.

Comment: A solution that worked for me https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/734497/245022

Answer (score 0):

Reading *dmesg* output I can say two things:

- first lines report an ACPI issue: have you tried to boot disabling ACPI with this kernel parameter `acpi=off`?
- sound HW seems well recognized and configured: do you hear any sound by executing this command `alsabat`?

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try the `acpi=off` and report back.  Issuing `alsabat` resulted in no sound, and this output: ```Playing generated audio sine wave
Entering capture thread (ALSA).
Get period size: 2756  buffer size: 22050
Recording ...
Playback completed.
Capture canceled.

BAT analysis: signal has 65536 frames at 44100 Hz, 1 channels, 2 bytes per sample.

Channel 1 - Checking for target frequency 997.00 Hz
Amplitude: 0.0; Percentage: [0]
WARNING: Signal too weak!
Detected at least 0 signal(s) in total

Return value is -1001```

Comment: Rebooted with `acpi=off`.  No change.  The `alsabat` test yielded the same result after reboot.  In case it helps, here are the boot parameters `rw quiet acpi=off acpi_osi=!Darwin acpi_backlight=video mds=full,nosmt`.

Comment: please, remove quiet and `acpi` parameters and give it a try

Comment: Tried with the other `acpi` settings removed, but keeping `acpi=off` **and** no `acpi` settings at all.  No luck.

Comment: I get the same output with `alsabat` but I have sound. Are you sure sound HW is not broken? Can you update the OP with updated outputs and clarify kernel parameters used?

Comment: The sound HW works when I boot into OSX; it is just on Linux that it does not work.  I'll update the OP with the kernel parameters and the `alsabat` results.  Should I include any other output?

Comment: At this point I have only one idea: did several reboots **directly into Linux** solve the issue?

Comment: No, I directly boot into Linux every time using rEFInd.