# No sound on an iMac 27 5k 2017 on Linux

Tags: linux, audio, intel

I just installed fedora 37 on an iMac 18,3. Everything is fine except there is no sound.

---

`settings/sound/`

- the selected output device is `Dummy output` and there is no other choice.
- there is no input.

`uname -srm`

```
Linux 6.1.8-200.fc37.x86_64 x86_64
```

`lpsci -v`

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 60
    Memory at 92720000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 61
    Memory at 92660000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

`lsmod | grep snd`

```
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_hda_codec_cs8409    36864  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_cs8409
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     86016  1
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_intel          61440  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         184320  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_cs8409,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core          114688  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_cs8409,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq                94208  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_pcm               151552  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   126976  18 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec_cs8409,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

`cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec`

```
Codec: Cirrus Logic CS8409
```

`cat /proc/asound/card1/codec* | grep Codec`

```
Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
```

---

From the search results, I see this a [known issue](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=imac+2017+linux+no+sound).

Most topics don't provide a solution.

[This topic](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=277990) seems to be similar, but it points to [this kernel module](https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409) which I don't know how to use.

Also, I tried

`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto,imac27
```

But it does not work.

---

Do you know how to have the audio input and output work on an iMac 27 on linux?

Thank you

Comment: File a bug report here https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Drivers under Sound (ALSA). Attach `alsa-info.sh` output: https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Help_To_Debug

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank you. Here is the bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216996

Comment: I also posted the auestion here https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/no-sound-on-an-imac-27-5k-2017/31450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [this module](https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409).

Instruction for Fedora 37:

```bash
# install the kernel headers
sudo dnf install kernel-devel

# clone the repo of the module
git clone https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409.git

# make and install
cd snd-hda-codec-cs8409
make
sudo make install
```

reboot.

---

Also, the mic input is now visible in the system settings but it still doesn't work (related: [issue on Github](https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409/issues/5), [question on stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734518/microphone-not-working-on-an-imac-27)).

Answer (score 0):

Its work also on Debian 12, thanks.

### With kernel headers installed

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-amd64 build-essential

git clone https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409.git
```

#### make and install

```
cd snd-hda-codec-cs8409
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot