# microphone not working on an imac 27

Tags: audio, microphone, pipewire

I installed Fedora on an imac 18,3 (27 5k 2017).

First, [audio didn't work at all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734192/no-sound-on-an-imac-27-5k-2017-on-linux). Eventually audio outputs work with [this module](https://github.com/egorenar/snd-hda-codec-cs8409).

After installing the module, I see a `Microphone - Built-in Audio` in the `Settings/Sound/Input` panel. But the mic input still does not work.

---

`arecord -l`

```bash
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CS8409/CS42L83 Analog [CS8409/CS42L83 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`wpctl status`

```bash
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, cookie:1752673102]
 └─ Clients:
        31. uresourced                          [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, pid:1662]
        32. WirePlumber                         [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, pid:1684]
        33. WirePlumber [export]                [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, pid:1684]
        39. pipewire-pulse                      [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, pid:1846]
        41. GNOME Shell Volume Control          [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, pid:1720]
        43. GNOME Volume Control Media Keys     [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, pid:2001]
        44. xdg-desktop-portal                  [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, pid:2228]
        57. GNOME Settings                      [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, pid:2594]
        72. libcanberra                         [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, pid:2001]
        73. wpctl                               [0.3.65, fr@imac-valerie, pid:3554]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      46. Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [alsa]
 │      47. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  *   54. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 0.82]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  *   55. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:
        58. GNOME Settings                                              
             60. input_FL        < CS8409/CS42L83 Analog:monitor_FL [active]
             61. monitor_FL     
             62. input_FR        < CS8409/CS42L83 Analog:monitor_FR [active]
             63. monitor_FR     
        59. GNOME Settings                                              
             64. input_FL        < CS8409/CS42L83 Analog:capture_FL [active]
             65. monitor_FL     
             66. input_FR        < CS8409/CS42L83 Analog:capture_FR [active]
             67. monitor_FR     

Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │      42. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)       [v4l2]
 │      45. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)       [v4l2]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │  *   48. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) (V4L2)
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Node Names:
```

---

How can I fix the microphone input?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For audio you've juste to install iMac driver made by Dadivjo :
[MacBook and iMac sound driver](https://github.com/davidjo/snd_hda_macbookpro)

But for input this driver have not this features, use an USB-C microphone may resolve your problem.

It's work on my iMac 18.1 (Cirrus Logic CS8409)

Distribution who work perfectly with m'y iMac :

- Ubuntu (last version) and Kali Linux
- Arch Linux : Manjaro and Xero Linux

Before install the driver, update and upgrade your systeme, reboot and see wich version lf linux is used with `uname -a`, while the installation of packages before the git clone and patch installation, at the `linux-header` package install step your package manager may ask wich version you have to install, select the compatible version with your kernel version, After you can git clone the repo and open the patch script, steps are in the readme.

Rare case : if the patch wouldn't be opened you Can make a

```
chmod +x patchscriptfile
```

Answer (score -1):

Warning !

do not start your computer with headphones or earphones plugged into a jack, take the time for it to be started and you can plug it in, the same for a microphone plugged into USB or USB-C.

Otherwise the speakers will not work or will make a big beep when you sound will be emitted

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, please consider adding links to external references for your statement. I personally have never experienced this kind of problem, so I am somewhat surprised about the strong statement in your answer.